# I can't make working keyCallback function in OpenGL and glfw

Tags: opengl, glfw, pyopengl

```py
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np

currentMode = GL_LINE_LOOP

def render(currentMode):


def key_callback(window, key, scancode, action, mods):
    if key==glfw.KEY_1:
        if action==glfw.PRESS:
            currentMode = GL_POINTS
    elif key==glfw.KEY_2:
        if action==glfw.PRESS:
            currentMode = GL_LINES
    elif key==glfw.KEY_3:
        if action==glfw.PRESS:
            currentMode = GL_LINE_STRIP

while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glfw.poll_events()
    render(currentMode)
    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    print(currentMode)
glfw.terminate()
```

I try to change primitive type to use render function's parameter. 
But, It doesn't work. 
What should I do?

Comment: I reduce a little part of my code. But core is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) in `key_callback`:

```py
def key_callback(window, key, scancode, action, mods):
    global currentMode # <--- THIS IS MISSING
   
    if key==glfw.KEY_1:
        if action==glfw.PRESS:
            currentMode = GL_POINTS
    # [...]
```

The variable `currentMode` exists twice. It is a variable in global namespace, and local variable in the scope of the function `key_callback`. Use the `global` statement to interpreted `currentMode` as global and to write to the  global variable `currentMode` with `key_callback`.

Of course the same applies to the `main` function, too:

```py
def main():
    global currentMode
    # [...]
```

Furthermore you have to clear the framebuffer in `render`:

```py
def render(currentMode):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
```

See the example:

```py
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np

def render(currentMode):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    
    print(currentMode)
    glBegin(currentMode)
    #Draw Something
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5)
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5)
    glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5)
    glEnd()

def key_callback(window, key, scancode, action, mods):
    global currentMode
    if key==glfw.KEY_1:
        if action==glfw.PRESS:
            currentMode = GL_POINTS
    elif key==glfw.KEY_2:
        if action==glfw.PRESS:
            currentMode = GL_LINES
    elif key==glfw.KEY_3:
        if action==glfw.PRESS:
            currentMode = GL_LINE_STRIP
    
def main():
    global currentMode

    if not glfw.init():
        return
    window = glfw.create_window(480, 480, "Test", None, None)
    
    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        return
    glfw.make_context_current(window)
    glfw.set_key_callback(window, key_callback)
    glfw.swap_interval(1)    

    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
        glfw.poll_events()
        render(currentMode)
        glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    glfw.terminate()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    currentMode = GL_LINE_LOOP
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, but redering didn't changed. I make print(currentMode) in loop and I checked this parameter changing... But rendering in screen doesn't change. I don't know why.
I made inital state of currentMode = GL_LINE_LOOP before main(), 
Should I change the location of code "currentMode = GL_LINE_LOOP"

Comment: def render(currentMode):
    #glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    
    glBegin(currentMode)
    #Draw 12 vertice
    glEnd()

Comment: https://community.khronos.org/t/rendering-doesnt-work-properly/105577      full code, there s no way to upload full code at stackoverflow

Comment: @MintStout I've extended the answer.

Comment: I'm reallllly thank you to your help. It does work!
If you don't mind, can you tell me why it wasn't working?
(explain more about 'global space')

Comment: @MintStout Thank you. You're welcome. I recommend to read the paragraph about [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) carefully.